# Setting radius per point

Tags: python, scripting, bezier-curves

I am trying to vary the radius of a thickened curve. To do so, I am using the function: `bpy.ops.curve.radius_set()`.

The manual says that I can set the radius per point, however I have not been able to do so. I want to dictate a radius for the start and end points of the curve. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The python console**

In object mode, have added the default bezier [curve](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Curve.html#module-bpy.types) object

The data part holds curve data

```
>>> cu = C.object.data
```

A curve is a set of splines, a [spline](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Spline.html#module-bpy.types) a set of points to define its shape.  Investigate spline 0

```
>>> spline = cu.splines[0]
```

Can auto complete in py console, eg pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> *Autocomplete key may differ see console menu or start message*

```
>>> spline.r<tab>
            adius_interpolation
            esolution_u
            esolution_v
            na_type
```

Hmm [radius interpolation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Spline.html#bpy.types.Spline.radius_interpolation), expect a radius property to be on the points, have 2 points

```
>>> for pt in spline.bezier_points:
...     pt
...     
bpy.data.curves['BezierCurve'].splines[0].bezier_points[0]
bpy.data.curves['BezierCurve'].splines[0].bezier_points[1]
```

whats the radius of the last

```
>>> pt.radius
1.0
```

set to 19

```
>>> pt.radius = 19
>>> pt.radius
19.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!